# Cannot install OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Iv'e installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04 on my system.
Now i would install the openjdk 8 package. The follwoing came out.

```
# apt install openjdk-8-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk
```

When I search in the apt cache the following is shown:

```
apt-cache search openjdk
default-jdk - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
default-jdk-doc - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (documentation)
default-jdk-headless - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (headless)
default-jre - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime
default-jre-headless - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime (headless)
openjdk-11-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-11-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-11-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-11-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-11-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-11-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-11-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
```

Has someone an idea what's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oke, I've found out by myself by reading the repository documentation.

You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your /etc/apt/sources.list like this:

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe

Comment: thx for this tip. FYI the magic word in this case is "universe". Maybe someone can explain what happened, here and why its missing in 18.04.1